# Coreplot legend with title, country label and under that line in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, core-plot

How to display the coreplot legend like this?

country flag,country name under that line(resembled in the graph)

[image]
func configureLegend() {
        guard let graph = hostView.hostedGraph else { return }

```
    let legend = CPTLegend(graph: graph)
    graph.legend = legend
    graph.legendAnchor = .topLeft
    graph.legendDisplacement = CGPoint(x: 50.0, y: -2.0)
    legend.fill = CPTFill(color: CPTColor.clear())
    legend.swatchSize = CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0)
    legend.numberOfRows = 1
    legend.entryPaddingBottom = 12
    let titleStyle = CPTMutableTextStyle()
    titleStyle.color = CPTColor.black()
    titleStyle.fontSize = 6.0
    titleStyle.fontName = Font.NissanPro_Bold
    legend.textStyle = titleStyle
    legend.delegate = self
}
public func legend(_ legend: CPTLegend, shouldDrawSwatchAt idx: UInt, for plot: CPTPlot, in rect: CGRect, in context: CGContext) -> Bool{
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can draw the flags using emoji, do that. Insert a newline (`\n`) character in the title text to position the text under the flag.

If you need to use custom graphics for the flags, use a legend `delegate` and implement the [`-legend:shouldDrawSwatchAtIndex:forPlot:inRect:inContext:`](http://core-plot.github.io/iOS/protocol_c_p_t_legend_delegate-p.html#af2f253e34078585116f32db12fb5ed12) delegate method. Draw the flag into the given graphics context inside the swatch rectangle and return `NO` to tell the legend that you took care of the required drawing.

To put the text under the graphic, enlarge the swatch size and draw both into the swatch rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric. But what is done the above implementation. that line moved to down(instead at center), not under the flag and text

Comment: You don't have to use the legend at all. Build up the view you want using Core Plot bordered layers (the flag graphic can be the `fill` for one of them) and a text layer. Attach this layer hierarchy to the graph as an annotation.